# How do I make a video using my webcam?

Tags: webcam, eeepc, avconv

I have an EEE PC 701 and want to record video using the built-in webcam. I have installed Lubuntu 14.10. I already have installed `avconv` and I want to use `avconv`.

Answer (score 2):

[If you want to use `avconv`](https://arashafiei.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/capture-video-and-audio-from-webcam-using-ffmpeg/)

Find video device

```
 ls /dev/video*
```

suppose video0

2- Find audio device

```
 arecord -l
```

suppose output like this

```
 card 1: U0x46d0x8ad [USB Device 0x46d:0x8ad],........
```

Then the audio device would be:

plughw:U0x46d0x8ad,0

Capture video and audio:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:U0x46d0x8ad,0 -ar 
22050 -ab 64k -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -y webcam.mp4
```

---

If you want to try some GUI apps:

**1.Camorama Webcam Viewer**

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install camorama
```

[image: Caomorana screenshot]

---

**2.GTK+ base UVC Viewer**

Install GUVC Viewer

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

[image]

Comment: I want to use avconv, the output of ls /dev/video* is /dev/video0 and the output of arecord -l is: 
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
What do I have to type?

Comment: `avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:Intel,0 -ar 
22050 -ab 64k -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -y webcam.mp4`

Comment: I get the error: `[alsa @ 0x976c3a0] cannot open audio device plughw:Intel,0 (No such device)
plughw:Intel,0: Input/output error`

Comment: Do you have input device such as microphone?>

Comment: Yes, I have a built-in microphone.

Comment: what is the command you run

Comment: I  run the command you give me: `avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:Intel,0 -ar 22050 -ab 64k -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -y webcam.mp4`

Comment: try this `avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:0x976c3a0,0 -ar 22050 -ab 64k -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -y webcam.mp4`

Comment: Now I get the error: `[alsa @ 0x85d03a0] cannot open audio device plughw:0x976c3a0,0 (No such device)
plughw:0x976c3a0,0: Input/output error`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23690/discussion-between-new-user-and-wb9688).

Comment: I've found the solution: `avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i plughw:0 -ar 22050 -ab 64k -strict experimental -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -y webcam.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

Go to application , Chose

> **cheese**

Cheese has an icon to record a video , Use that .

Simple as few clicks